# Cannot browse a H2 database file?

Tags: h2, dbvisualizer

I am creating a H2 database in my unit tests. The database uses the following properties:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
    destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:file:target/db/testdb"/>
  <property name="username" value="sa"/>
  <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>
```

I am using version 1.3.166 of the `com.h2database.h2` jar file.

When I run my tests, I see the database created in `target/db` directory, and a `testdb.h2.db` file exists. My tests run and load data from the database. I can open the `target/db/testdb.h2.db` file and see the SQL statements that I used to create the database.

However, when I try to load the `target/db/testsb.h2.db` file into a database browsing tool such as DBVisualizer, I cannot see any tables or data. For DBVisualizer I specify the H2(Embedded) mode.

I also tried the H2 console but a `show tables` command returns an empty result set.

I can't see what I am doing wrong: the database file exists, the tests run against it correctly, but I cannot open this file in a database browser.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely, the problem is the database URL you use.

```
jdbc:h2:file:target/db/testdb
```

This means the database file is stored ***relative to the current working directory***. So it depends where you started the application. If you started DBVisualizer in a different directory (which most likely you did), then it's creating a *new* database in a different directory.

To ensure you are using the same database, I suggest to use an absolute directory name, or relative to the current user home directory, as described in the H2 documentation:

```
jdbc:h2:~/relative/to/user/home/dir/testdb
jdbc:h2:/absolute/path/testdb
```

The prefix `file:` is optional.

Comment: Actually the problem was how I specified the file in DBVisualizer. It asked for a database file, and opens a file chooser dialog, and I naturally double-clicked on the `target/db/testdb.h2.db` file. But the correct method is to remove the `.h2.db` extension. Bad UI design IMHO.

Comment: I think in the next mayor version of H2 (2.0 maybe) there will be no hardcoded file name suffix.

Comment: @JohnQCitizen You win all my internet for a week! This was the issue. I was using database migrations and couldn't figure out why the tables weren't created. Turned out that removing .h2.db did the trick. Use ui fail! And thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

If you get an error like

```
Unsupported database file version or invalid file header in file "Old database:
/path/to/databasename.data.db - please convert the database to a SQL script and 
re-create it." [90048-167]
```

the problem is (as the message says) that you are using a database created with an old version of h2. In order to browse the database with dbVisualizer you can create a new database driver:

`Tools` > `Driver manager...` > `Create a new driver`

Fill in the fields and select the right h2 jar file, and you should be good to go.